# Возможно подключить Git к серверу?

Tags: git, сервер, github

Здравствуйте, поискал в интернете не нашёл что мне нужно(наверное не так вопрос формулировал).Возможно ли подключить git к серверу, и отслуживать файлы на сервере, и если нужно закачивать на github.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы изменения в файлах на сервере автоматически коммитились в репозиторий и отправлялись на гитхаб?

Comment: Можно, все можно.

способ первый, правильный - поставить git на сервере. Дальше все тривиально.

способ второй - подмонтировать папку с сервера себе в локальную папку (для этого можно использовать как ssh, так и другие средства) и тогда каталоги сервера будут "локальные". После этого задача опять же стает тривиальной.

Comment: @Nofate Не автоматически, хоть чтобы я мог их коммитить и отправлять на github.

Comment: @KoVadim Вот именно, как поставить git на сервере?

Comment: Ну там `sudo apt install git` или `sudo yum install git` - смотря что за сервер. Как любой другой пакет, в общем.

Comment: @Nofate Спасибо большое! То что искал :)